# Is there a limit on the maximum number of ejabberd nodes in a cluster?

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, erlang-otp

What is the maximum number of nodes that can be in a single cluster in ejabberd ? Is there any limit on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a listing of the various Erlang limits in the documentation: http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/advanced.html#id70130

You don't get numbers for all of those, because they're configurable, but they're high enough that I doubt you'll reach any of them. However, there are effective limits that are much lower: the network bandwidth connecting all the servers to each other and to the clients is probably the piece that will fail first under a massive number of servers. How much bandwidth your severs have is up to you. How much bandwidth they need is also (mostly) up to you. You'll have to use load-tests to discover what resources you think you need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is limit in the size of a cluster. The cost of synchronization grows with the number of node in the cluster.

The actual limit however depends on the exact architecture of you messaging system. Depending on your need and requirements, you can definitely find ways to make the limit very large.